How to check if the first 3 cells are greater than the other first 3 cells in two tables
I basically have two tables that track scores. All I am wanting is to add up the number of 'Sweeps' or number of times in one table (will use the same formula for the other table) where the first 3 games in a row are all greater than the other person's first 3 games in the other table (if the person wins (green) 3 games in a row, that should count as 1). 

So in the picture below the 2nd and 3rd row of scores in the first table would add up to 2 for Johnny. The 4th row of scores in the 2nd table would add up to 1 for Derek.

This is what I have tried but apparently doesn't work like I thought it would since it still came back with zeroes (scores begin on row 9 and end on row 201):
=SUM(IF(AND(M9:M201>S9:S201,N9:N201>T9:T201,O9:O201>U9:U201),1,0))

I deleted my answer because my answer is for the wrong problem. I wrongly interpreted you wanting to test all of the five Games, looking for any 3 consecutive "wins". But I see you are only interested in the first three, which is a much simpler issure.

Correct. I’m wanting to see if a “sweep” happens where the person wins the first three games consecutively. I’m also wanting to check for reverse sweeps where one person wins the first two games and then the other wins the next three consecutively. But I figured for this last one I want I can just specify the array to look at games 3, 4 and 5 basically.

If you don't mind using helper columns, an easy approach would be:

Helper column for John (drag down)
=IF(AND(B4>G4;C4>H4;D4>I4);1;0)

Helper column for Derek (drag down)
=IF(AND(G4>B4;H4>C4;I4>D4);1;0)

The just sum up both columns like I did at bottom

As an aside, your formula can be shortened to =N(AND(B4:D4>G4:I4))

I went with your method and just hid the helper columns so they can't be seen. Thanks!
